# What is the best way to return an array from a function using recursion

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I have the following code below with one major flaw. Every time the recursion works (i.e. the function is called more than once) it overwrites the array because of the var result = [] expression. So, what is the best way in order to avoid this. I really don't want to put the result variable outside the scope of the function. What I'm looking for are best practices and better ways of doing this.

```
function getElementNames(obj){
    //below line overwrites the previous result every time this function runs
    var result = [];
    if(!obj.parent){
        result.push(obj.name);
    }
    else {
        result.push(obj.name);
        getElementNames(obj['parent'])
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @Xufox: sorry, my mistake. I fixed it

Comment: `var result` doesn't overwrite because it's a local variable. Each call into getElementNames gets its own `result` variable. What's happening is you're not using the result of the other calls to `getElementNames` (you're discarding the parents result)

Comment: If you change the recursive part of your code to `result.push(obj.name);result.push(getElementNames(obj.parent))` then you'll see something. But the resulting structure may not be what you want. See Nina's answer for the classical way of doing this

Comment: @slebetman: not sure I fully understand. you're saying that var result = [] doesn't reset the result every time? i thought that's what was happening...

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. Each function call gets its own `result` variable. But you discard it (not use the return value) when you recurse

Comment: so, each time the function runs, it creates a result in memory with one value, but they are not there because they are discarded, right?

Comment: @user1142130 every function call *creates* an array and returns it, to concat to the array of the caller function. This is what happens in Nina's answer. In mine, it uses the same array created and by reference it adds the new items. That's the main difference between them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you change the whole structure a bit. I recommend to return an array and concat if necessary.

```
function getElementNames(obj) {
    var result = [obj.name];
    if (obj.parent) {
        result = result.concat(getElementNames(obj.parent));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: this works, however, how is the line var result = [obj.name] not the same problem as i had with var result = []?

Comment: that was not really the problem. the problem is, every instance of `getElementNames` has it's own result, independently. that is, what i have changed to `result = result.concat(...)`. this grants the return values from every call of `getElementNames`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the *same* `result`:

```
function getElementNames(obj, result){
    // This lines creates the first array, no need to pass it in the function call
    if (!result) {
        result = [];
    }

    if(!obj.parent){
        result.push(obj.name);
    }
    else {
        result.push(obj.name);
        getElementNames(obj['parent'], result)
    }
    return result;
}
```

So, all function levels manages the same `result` created at the beggining by reference.

Example:

```js
function getElementNames(obj, result){
    // This lines creates the first array, no need to pass it in the function call
    if (!result) {
        result = [];
    }

    if(!obj.parent){
        result.push(obj.name);
    }
    else {
        result.push(obj.name);
        getElementNames(obj['parent'], result)
    }
    
    return result;
};

var el = {
    name: "Element 1",
    parent: {
        name: "Element 2",
        parent: {
            name: "Element 3"
        }
    }
};

var r = getElementNames(el);
console.log(r);
```